# Custom Search Suggestions Android

Tags: android, search

I am trying to make search suggestions. What I am trying to do is when user enters query I send HTTP Requests to server and fetch the JSON response and save it in database using Content Provider and Content Resolver.

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, query, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SearchActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("query",query);
                startActivity(intent);

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                Log.d("Text Changing", newText);
                if(newText.length() > 3){
                    String url = "https://www.xxxxx.com/xxxx/v1/volumes?q=" + newText + "&key=" + getResources().getString(R.string._api_key);
                    try {
                        HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest(url,MainActivity.this);
                        httpRequest.execute();
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }

  void jsonParse(String jsonString) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        StringBuilder mAuthors = new StringBuilder();
        if (jsonObject != null) {
            JSONArray itemArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
            for (int i = 0; i < itemArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject itemObject = itemArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject volumeInfo = itemObject.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
                if (volumeInfo.has("title"))
                {
                    Log.d("titles",volumeInfo.getString("title"));
                    contentValues.put(BookContract.BookRow.BOOK_NAME,volumeInfo.get("title").toString());
                }
                if (volumeInfo.has("authors")) {
                    JSONArray authorArray = volumeInfo.getJSONArray("authors");
                    if (volumeInfo.getJSONArray("authors") != null) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < authorArray.length(); j++) {
                            mAuthors.append(volumeInfo.get("authors")+"\n");
                        }
                        contentValues.put(BookContract.BookRow.BOOK_AUTHOR,mAuthors.toString());
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        //contentResolver.delete(BookContract.BookRow.CONTENT_URI,null,null);
        contentResolver.insert(BookContract.BookRow.CONTENT_URI,contentValues);
    }
```

Now I don't know that to write in Content Provider query method, So that it display search suggestions.

Comment: just use `SearchView#setSuggestionsAdapter` and pass the `SimpleCursorAdapter` with setup `FilterQueryProvider`

Comment: @pskink can you give an example of it?

Comment: for testing just use this adapter: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830, pass it to `SearchView#setSuggestionsAdapter` method

Comment: @pskink I don't need any database or content provider ?? with that solution??

Comment: no, no need for a custom `ContentProvider`

Comment: @pskink thanks dude... gonna try and then upvote the answer :P

Comment: @pskink one more thing, how will i add click on the suggestions and get clicked item so that i can show proper results?

Comment: how? by reading `android.widget.SearchView` javadocs